# Improper integral from 1 to infinity $\Rightarrow$ integrated function converges towards zero?

Tags: analysis, improper-integrals

Let $f: [1, \infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function such that the improper integral $$\int_1^\infty f(x) \ dx$$ exists. Show or disprove that $\lim \limits _{x \to \infty} f(x) =0$.

Our professor said that there are counterexamples but after frying my brain out I still could not find any. It does sound logical.

Comment: And by the way, f is continuous.

Comment: It's worth noting that if we additionally assume that $f'$ or $f''$ is bounded makes this true (and I would guess that if $f^{(n)}$ is bounded for any $n\geq 1$, it is true as well)

Answer (score 16):

It does sound plausible, especially by analogy with infinite series. But yes, there are counterexamples. Here's one:

Consider a continuous function that is zero, except for triangles centered on the integers, of height 1 and area going like $1/2^n$. Then the integral will exist but the function itself doesn't converge to zero.

*Added:* A rough diagram (graph of function with is zero  for all $x \geq 1$ except for two sides of isosceles triangles of height 1, base length $2^{-(n-2)}$ centered over each integer $n \geq 2$; the area of the triangle over the integer $n$ is $2^{-(n-1)}$.)

[image]

Then for such a function,
$$\lim_{x\to\infty} \int_1^x f(x) \ dx = \lim_{N\to\infty} \sum_{n=2}^N 2^{-(n-1)} = 1$$

however $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)$ does not exist.

The counterexample can be made more exotic by allowing it be unbounded: let the isosceles triangle over integer $n$ have height $n/2$ and base length $(n2^{n-3})^{-1}$; each triangle's area remains $2^{-(n-1)}$.

Comment: I forgot to add that f is a continuous, important detail which I added now.

Comment: His example is continuous as well.

Comment: The example I am describing is continuous. Get the picture in your head and then you should be able to write down an explicit definition.

Comment: alright , thank you .

Comment: I thought about it , still couldn't really picture , is there a specific type of function which fits in to your counterexample?

Comment: @SimonS Look at my example of an infinitely differentiable satisfying OP's criteria.

Comment: @samwise hopefully the picture is clear now.

Answer (score 8):

Here is a simple counter example.
$$f(x) = \begin{cases} 1 & \text{ if }x \in \mathbb{Z}^+\\ 0 & \text{ otherwise}\end{cases}$$

---

In case you are after an infinitely differentiable function, consider $f(x) = \sin(x^2)$. We have $$\int_0^{\infty} \sin\left(x^2 \right) dx = \dfrac12 \sqrt{\dfrac{\pi}2}$$
but $\lim_{x \to \infty} \sin\left(x^2 \right)$ doesn't exist.

Comment: This is not continuous, alas

Comment: @SimonS Where does the OP say the function has to be continuous?

Comment: I added it now in the comments.

Comment: @dennis Added another function, which is infinitely differentiable satisfying your criteria.

Comment: @SimonS Added another function, which is infinitely differentiable satisfying the OP's criteria.

Comment: Haha can't believe I couldn't think of that , I thank you very much.

Comment: Why does the integral of your first function exist?

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD It is easy to show that the first one is even Riemann integrable. The second one is just the error integral after appropriate massaging.

Answer (score 0):

You may even have positive continuous unbounded functions with an existing improper integral.

You can have a look [here](http://www.mathcounterexamples.net/unbounded-continuous-function-with-finite-integral/) with some pictures.