# Are there functions that are not of exponential order for which you can define a Laplace transform?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

I'am in a course of Introduction to Linear Differential Equations and teacher made us this question in class.

we work in $\mathbb{R}$, and any help to answer this is welcome

Comment: What do you mean by define a Laplace transformation? A function having a Laplace transformation not being of exponential order?

Comment: Yes. Look at the second counterexample I describe here (in reference to a different question): http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1264766/improper-integral-from-1-to-infinity-integrated-function-converges-towards-zer/1264769#1264769

That function will not be of exponential type, as it is unbounded as $x \to \infty$. However the Laplace transform integral of it converges.

Comment: @SimonS, you are right!, also $f(x)=0$ iff $x\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $f(x)=0$ otherwise. thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}$A prime example that you find in many textbooks is

$$
f(t) = 2te^{t^2}\cos(e^{t^2})
$$

We may observe that $f(t)=\frac{\dd}{\dd t}\sin(e^{t^2})$, therefore,

\begin{align}
(\mathscr{L}f)(s)
{}={}& 
\int_0^\infty e^{-s\tau} \frac{\dd}{\dd \tau}\sin(e^{\tau^2}) \dd \tau
\\
{}={}& \left.e^{-s\tau}\sin(e^{\tau^2})\right|_0^\infty
- \int_0^\infty (-s)e^{-s\tau}\sin(e^{\tau^2})\dd\tau
\\
{}={}& -\sin 1 - \int_0^\infty (-s)e^{-s\tau}\sin(e^{\tau^2})\dd\tau
\end{align}

The last integral converges because

\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty (-s)e^{-s\tau}\sin(e^{\tau^2})\dd\tau
{}\leq{}& 
\left|\int_0^\infty (-s)e^{-s\tau}\sin(e^{\tau^2})\dd\tau\right|
\\
{}={}&\int_0^\infty s e^{-s\tau}|\sin(e^{\tau^2})|\dd\tau
\\
{}\leq{}& \int_0^\infty s e^{-s\tau}\dd\tau
{}={} \frac{1}{s},
\end{align}

so the integral is defined for $s\in \mathbb{C}$ with $\Re(s) > 0$.

There are several other examples such as the one mentioned by @SimonS in a comment (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1264766/improper-integral-from-1-to-infinity-rightarrow-integrated-function-converges/1264769#1264769)).

Yet another example is the following function

$$
f(t) = \begin{cases}
e^{n^2}, &\text{if } t\in [n, n+e^{-n^2})
\\
0,&\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

It is not difficult to show that the Laplace transform of $f$ exists.

Answer (score 0):

A good example is $\ln x$ .

Its laplace transform is $-\dfrac{\gamma+\ln s}{s}$ .

Comment: $lnx$, is of exponential order 1.